# Can I exit Canada for a couple of days to renew my status as a visitor?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, multiple-entry, visa-runs

I am currently in Canada as a tourist, however, according to the [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/extend-stay.asp) I am only allowed to remain in Canada as a visitor for a total of 6 months. My question is, if I were to leave Canada and go to the US for a couple of days and then return to Canada will my status as a visitor be "renewed" i.e. would I be able to stay in Canada for another six months?

I should clarify that my visitor visa expires in 2024. Also just to provide some context, my son will be out of University by May 10, and we had both originally planned to return back to our country together. I have already applied for a status extension but I am afraid the processing times might take too long, hence why the question.

Comment: I don't know about Canada, but in countries I am familiar with a pending application for extension of status allows you to stay until the application is decided.  Furthermore, leaving the country typically constitutes *withdrawal* of the application, and you are liable, if not likely, to be refused entry when you try to return.

Comment: Oli_ver18 what is your nationality?

Comment: JacobHorbulyk Both me and my son are from Honduras.

Comment: Don't forget the Americans could very possibly even deny you entry because you've spent a lot of time in Canada and they could see it's like you're making a home in Canada. Six months is a long time.

Comment: I've seen people doing this but for a US B1 visa, and they remain off for 2 weeks and not only a few days.